# Objective-c - Sort some Numbers stored is variables

Tags: objective-c, ios4, sorting

hello
I want to sort(ascending) some numbers stored in different variables(like int a=50,int b=60, etc..)!
How can i do that?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: How many variables? Is there any problem if you use array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to store the numbers in an NSArray, packaged in NSNumbers. Then you can do normal array sorting:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:a],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:b],
    nil
];

NSArray *sorted = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them into NSArray or NSMutableArray and sort the array

Comment: You can't just stick `int`s into an NSArray -- you need to create NSNumbers first.

Comment: I meant it is obvious to wrap them in NSNumber

Comment: it's obvious to you and me, but probably not obvious to someone who's not familiar with NSArray. The OP obviously isn't, otherwise they wouldn't be asking about sorting numbers.